# Store the total volume of the items from a WooCommerce order in the DB

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, orders

I am not really sure of what I am doing, but in a nutshell I want to calculate the volume of all items from an order and store it in the DB. I am working with the woocommerce Rest API and when I retrieve the order I don't have the 3 measures of the item bought so I thought to do as I have already done with the total weight stored as a meta data in the db and then retrieved trough the API.

I am using the following:

```
// Store volume in the database
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_add_cart_volume');

function woo_add_cart_volume( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

     foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product_volume = (float) get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_item_volume', true );
        $total_volume  += $product_volume * $item->get_quantity();
    }
    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_item_volume', $total_volume );
}
```

But it breaks the process of the order and throws an Internal server Error.

Can you help me to adjust it?

Comment: `foreach( $order->`, `$order` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missing parts in your code:

- The  `$order` need to be defined before using `get_items()` method on it,
- Also `$total_volume` need to be initialized before.

Use instead:

```
// Store volume in the database
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_add_cart_volume');

function woo_add_cart_volume( $order_id ) {
    $order        = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // <== Was missing
    $total_volume = 0; // Initializing variable

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product_volume = (float) get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_item_volume', true );
        $total_volume  += $product_volume * $item->get_quantity();
    }
    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_item_volume', $total_volume );
}
```

Now it should better work.

Comment: Thank you. It works but something we are missing. i placed a order to try it out. I retrieved orders trough the rest Api and i see this:
```
{
                "id": 311972,
                "key": "_cart_weight",
                "value": "26"
            },
            {
                "id": 311973,
                "key": "_item_volume",
                "value": "0"
            },
```
The volume is 0.. i checked the object and has the 3 dimensions. Why is it 0? What are me missing? thank you

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to do.. now i accepted it. I know that you are really good at it because i saw other answers you gave on this matter: I think that we first need to calculate the volume and than store it as a parameter in the _item_volume' meta data. 
can you help me on this?

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec You mean opening a new question in the main section?